# socket.makefile() equivalent in Node JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, network-programming

[socket.makefile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) is a Python method from its standard-library `socket` module. It makes working with sockets more comfortable - especially if you want to replace local file operations with socket communication without further adjustments.

It makes a socket object a regular file handle, meaning that you can apply operations like `write` and `readlines`.

Is there an equivalent function available in Node JS? If not, what code could I use to implement this feature?

<sup>Note: If you know a 3rd-party library, please propose it as a comment since non-external-libs answers are the goal of this question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pass a seperate [file descriptor](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) with your socket options to get this behaviour. [Source](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)

net.Socket already has a write method implemented. Reading is asynchronously implemented though. Probably best for the environment. You listen to the on("data") event. To synchronize it you may need to use Promises with async/await sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that 100% turns a socket into a file object, since Node doesn't really have a `File` class anyway. But you can combine different parts of the Node standard library into something similarly ergonomic:

```js
import { createInterface } from 'readline';
import { connect } from 'net';
import { on } from 'events';

const createSocket = (port, host) => {
  const socket = connect(port, host);

  const rl = createInterface({ input: socket });

  const lines = on(rl, 'line');

  return {
    readline: () => lines.next().then(({ value }) => value),
    write: (data) => socket.write(data),
  };
};

const socket = createSocket(8080, 'localhost');

socket.write('Hello World');
const response = await socket.readline();
```